# List all buckets under a project from the google storage using Storage JSON API in Python

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am referring below link and below that, I have pasted a copy of my code.
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/storage/v1/storage.buckets.list

```
   import requests
   response = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=
   {YOUR_PROJECT_NAME}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}')
   print(response.json())
```

When I try to access it it gives me below error

```
{'error': {'errors': [{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'required', 'message': 'Anonymous users does not have storage.buckets.list access to project 72
8242242638.', 'locationType': 'header', 'location': 'Authorization'}], 'code': 401, 'message': 'Anonymous users does not have storage.buckets.list a
ccess to project 728242242638.'}}
```

What part I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing authentication. An API key identifies a project, but it doesn't provide any sort of authentication. Google doesn't know that you're really a user allowed to view the access token.

If you want to see your command work real quick and you have the `gcloud` SDK installed, run `gcloud auth print-access-token`. That will give you a string like ya29.blibbity_blabbity. Attach a header to your request that reads `Authorization: Bearer ya29.blibbity_blabbity`, and your request should succeed.

Access tokens are only good for 5 minutes or so, and you shouldn't hardcode them into your code. You'll need a more permanent solution. The easiest way forward is to just use a higher level Google Cloud library, like [google-cloud](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/), but if you want to keep using requests directly, you'll want to start by learning more of the details of Google Cloud's auth. Start here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Thank you for the detailed explanation. Let me figure out whether to use Cloud library or simple API. Will update once I figure it out. Thanks again.